# Update UILabel based on selected table view rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a table view and a text field. Whatever the person selects in that table view will appear in the textfield.

Example: In my table view are the choices "one" "two" "three"

If I select "one", a checkmark appears on my tableview and "one" will appear in my text field as well.

I know how to add strings together by using stringByAppendingString, so when I select "two", and "one" is still selected, my label will appear as "onetwo"

Now for my question: If I were to DESELECT the "one" choice (or any other choice for that matter), how can I delete just a certain portion of this concatenated string?

Example: If I selected in this order "threeonetwo" and I wanted to deselect "one", my label will appear now as "threetwo".

Thank you.

UPDATE: This is what I have done so far and I am stuck.

First: I created a mutable array:

NSMutableArray *toBeFilledTableData;

Then I allocated it:

toBeFilledTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Then, if the user selects the option from the table view, I would add the one object:

[toBeFilledTableData addObject:@"one"];

I changed my mind on having the textfield appear as "threeonetwo", I'd like to add a semicolon in between so instead I want the appearance to be "three;one;two". So created a string to add a semicolon at the end:

NSString *combinedForces

combinedForces = [toBeFilledTableData componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
(^ but that is not displaying my semicolon so instead I'll just add the semicolon to addObject [unless there is another way to do it])

Then I displayed the object in my text field:

textField.text = combinedForces;

So as of right now, 1. my list is not populating as I click more options and 2. inserting the semicolon in between each choice is becoming a puzzle. I'd appreciate any help =)

Comment: edited my answer according to your new update,please check

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting that portion of the string, you could maintain an array or set with the selected items.

In the `didSelectRowAtIndex` path method you add the selected string to the array (or remove it) and call an `updateLabel` method, which creates a string from the contents of the array or set.

Thus, your string is recreated every time a change happens.

---

If you want to know the order of the selection, use an `NSMutableOrderedSet`, if you don't need to know the order, you can use an `NSMutableSet`.

Comment: Cool, I already had an Array for the table view:    NSArray *tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

I don't want to delete anything from the tableview, just from label appearance. How would I go about that?

Comment: You have a separate array for the selected objects. At first, it's empty, when a row is selected, you add the object (string) to it, and later remove it on deselect.

Comment: This is what I did: I created my mutable array: NSMutableArray *toBeFilledTableData;

Then I allocated it: toBeFilledTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Then I added just one object: [toBeFilledTableData addObject:@"one"];

Then I displayed the object as my label: 

textField.text = [toBeFilledTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

And it displays just fine. Now if I want to DESELECT it, I added the code: 

[toBeFilledTableData removeObject:@"one"]; 

Question: Now how do I set my label? 

Because textField.text = [toBeFilledTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; doesn't work.

Comment: @the_fez Don't post a bunch of code in a comment. If needed, update your question with further details so people see it and can read it when viewing your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with below code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath & didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

```
NSString *lblString = @"";
    NSArray *indexPathArray = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    for(NSIndexPath *index in indexPathArray)
    {
        NSString *subStr = [arrayDatasource objectAtIndex:index.row]; //perticular choice from your choice array
        if([indexPathArray lastObject]!=index)
        {
            lblString = [lblString stringByAppendingString:[subStr stringByAppendingString:@";"]];
        }
         else  
        {
           lblString = [lblString stringByAppendingString:subStr];
        }



    }
```

Comment: Don't put this code in both methods. Put this code in its own method and call it from the two table view delegate methods. You should also use a mutable string instead of appending and reassigning the immutable string.